# Grouping changes of different element's styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible in Javascript to set different element's styles at once, in such way that only one reflow is triggered? For example, is it possible to set at once the color style for different elements as in the below code snippet, in a way that just one reflow is triggered instead of three reflows?

```
document.getElementById("elem1").style.color = '#000';
document.getElementById("elem2").style.color = '#fff';
document.getElementById("elem3").style.color = '#abc';
```

I am familiar with techniques (as explained [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/02/03/speed-up-your-javascript-part-4/)) that minimize reflows/repaints such as using document fragments or using css classes instead of manipulating css styles through javascript, but I don't see how they can be applied on this case.

**EDIT**: the three elements on the example are siblings but there might exist, or not, other sibling elements between them, meaning that we cannot assume that they are defined necessarily by that order in the html structure. For example, its possible that we have a structure like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="elem1">elem1</div>
    <div id="elem2">elem2</div>
    <div id="elem4">elem4</div>
    <div id="elem3">elem3</div>
</div>
```

Much appreciated for any help!

Cheers

Comment: depends on html structure. If those elements are only elements within a parent for example could manipulate them outside the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please be aware that I've edited my question regarding the html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware the is no way to set the class of multiple elements at once. However, the browser may actually batch these changes for you anyway. Providing you don't read styles *as well as* writing them I believe this should hold true.

This article provides some insight into how reflow and repaint are triggered http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare class like this :

```
.color1{
color : #000;
} 

.color2{
color : #abc;
}
```

And set to your elements like this :

```
document.getElementById("elem1").className = document.getElementById("elem1").className + " color1";
document.getElementById("elem2").className = document.getElementById("elem2").className + " color2";
```

Comment: But wouldnt changing the classname of each of the three elements still trigger three reflows? Also, be aware that I've edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your element structure. For example assuming those elements are sibling DIVs, you can define CSS as:

```
div.myclass {
    color:#000
}

div.myclass + div {
    color:#fff
}

div.myclass + div + div {
    color:#abc
}
```

Then a single JS command:

```
document.getElementById("elem1").className = "myclass";
```

Would set color for all 3: http://jsfiddle.net/PjZ77/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answser, but what about if there are other sibling elements in between those elements? Sorry for missing this detail on my question. I've edited my question.

Comment: In that case you can target any specific sibling using `first-child`, `last-child` or `nth-child`: http://jsfiddle.net/PjZ77/2/ or even directly target specific IDs and still use one assignment command http://jsfiddle.net/PjZ77/3/

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense in your case, use css classes and swap the container class.

HTML structure could be :

```
  <div id="container1">
    <div id="elem1" class="clsA">A</div>
    <div id="elem2" class="clsB">B</div>
    <div id="elem3" class="clsC">C</div>
  </div>
```

and in CSS:

```
  #container1 .clsA { color: #000; }
  #container1 .clsB { color: #111; }
  #container1 .clsC { color: #222; }

  #container1.mystate .clsA { color: #DDD; }
  #container1.mystate .clsB { color: #EEE; }
  #container1.mystate .clsC { color: #FFF; }
```

You can set `document.getElementById("container1").className` with `mystate` class (or empty class, or any class name that makes sense you defined in the css.

Class change occurs for only one element (the container), so the elem(n) child items will be refreshed at the same moment.